# Array insert sqlite helper problem insert

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, retrofit

I need help , for insert data in sqllite from ArrayList

My code:

```java
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Campos>> call, Response<List<Campos>> response) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
        mJsonTxtView.setText("Codigo: " + response.code());
        return;
    }
    List<Campos> camposList = response.body();
    for (Campos campos: camposList){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        String content = "";
        String Proyecto= campos.getsProyecto();
        String Nombre = campos.getsNombre();
        String Estado = campos.getsEstado();
        Integer Activo= campos.getnActivo();
        MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);
        helper.saveCampos(Proyecto, Nombre, Estado, Activo);
    }

}
```

Error in MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous Callback<List<Campos>>> cannot be converted to Context
                    MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);
```

My helper create db

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Proyecto (ProyectoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ZoneName integer,ProyectoName text, ZoneStateId integer, EstadoName text, Codigo text)");
}
```

My helper insert function

```java
public void saveCampos(String proyecto, String nombre, String estado,Integer activo) {
    SQLiteDatabase helper = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(proyecto, proyecto );
    values.put(nombre, nombre );
    values.put(estado, estado );
    values.put(estado, activo );

    helper.insert(proyecto,null, values);
    helper.close();
}
```

Could you help me, how can I solve it to insert.

MyHelper Classs , 
Here I leave the helper class of sqlite, where if the data from the array reaches the mentioned class savecampos:

```
public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Cursor cursorLogs;
private String query = "";
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context;
public static final String dbname ="datauser.db";
        private static final int version = 1;
public MyHelper(Context context){
    super(context, dbname, null, version);
   }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Proyecto (ProyectoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ZoneName integer,ProyectoName text, ZoneStateId integer, EstadoName text, Codigo text)");}

public void saveCampos(String proyecto, String nombre, String estado, Integer activo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("proyecto", proyecto );
    values.put("nombre", nombre );
    values.put("estado", estado );
    values.put("activo", activo );
    db.insert(proyecto,null, values);
    db.close();
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

My class call code to retrofit:

```
public class SplashActivity extends MainActivity {
Context mContext;
private static Context context;
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SplashActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
}
public static Context getAppContext() {
    return SplashActivity.context;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    retrofit retrofit = new retrofit();
    retrofit.getCampos();


    // 5 seconds pause on splash page
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLoggedIn()){
                //Redirect to home page
                intent = new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }else{
                //Redirect to Login Page
                intent = new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    },5000);
}
public void init() {
    context = this;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

can you help me

Comment: The `this` in your case is referring to the callback instance which is not a context so it's invalid - use a valid `Context` instance such as the containing `<class>.this` reference or other context - is this code in an activity?  Why are you creating a Helper on every loop iteration - create it once in activity create for example.

Comment: I access from another class

whit next code: 
Call:  retrofit retrofit = new retrofit();
        retrofit.getCampos();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit `onResponse()` takes an anonymous inner class arugment, so any code inside refers to this inner class; therefore `this` refers to an instance other than the `context`, to get a context, just juse `getApplicationContext()` or use `MyActivity.this`.

So, change this

```
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);
```

to:

```
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

Or to:

```
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(MyActivity.this);
```

Change `MyActivity` with your activity name that surrounds your code snippet.

Comment: thank you again, the again error: 
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: sorry for asking so much but I get this error:

the again error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @LUISMADRID no worries man .. we here to learn from one another .. it seems that the `Retrofit` may run before the activity is completely created, and hence `getApplicationContext()` returns null; so you can try a couple of things either use the other suggested solution at the answer by using `MyActivity.this` or you can use a class local field named `Context mContext` and intialize it in `onCreate()`  like `mContext = getApplicationContext();`, then use it in your `MyHelper` instance

Comment: Do I need to extend my class?

 public class retrofit  {

Comment: @LUISMADRID no just try the above comment suggestion

Comment: Thanks you. I work with : MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(com.example.appcourse.retrofit.retrofit.this);
///////////////////////
but in my Sqllhelper: 

  public MyHelper(Context context){
        super(context, dbname, null, version);
        SQLiteDatabase dbname = this.getWritableDatabase();
        dbname.close();
    }
///////////////
Error: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you edit your question with the your MyHelper class and the error you got so that it can be more readable

Comment: ready, I already put the helper class and the class with which I call the retrofit class